# How can I config git submodule branch in Jenkins？

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

In the "Additional Behaviours >>  Advanced sub-modules" behaviours option, I can't see the submodule branch to select.

Does it selects master by default or I can config branch in other way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I mention  in [Git submodules: Specify a branch/tag](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18799234/6309), your parent repo should include a `.gitmodules` in which you can specify the branch.

```
git config -f .gitmodules submodule.<path>.branch <branch>
```

But if that is not enough, make sure your first build step (or pre-build step) is a

```
git submodule update --remote
```

Comment: @lgallard Thank you. I have edited the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

You can configure submodule branch name in your project's `.gitmodules` file manually.

```
[submodule "XXXXXXXXXX"]
    path = XXXXXXXXXX
    url = YOUR_SUBMODULE_GIT_URL
    branch = SUBMODULE_BRANCH_NAME
```

You have selected and configured `advanced submodule behaviour` for your project. After modifying above mentioned file, build your project. It will fetch and update your submodule with your configured branch mentioned as above.